# How to call SQL Server 2005 stored procedure from Oracle?

Tags: sql-server-2005, oracle, procedure

I have created procedure in SQL Server 2005. And now I want to call this procedure via database link in Oracle... Can you help me?

Comment: do you need to directly call the SQL SP from Oracle or are you open to adopt a more flexible approach to involve an application to acheive this?

Comment: @Bumble Bee Thank you for your response.
Yes directly.   I used the following:  BEGIN sqlstproc@dblink END;


But doesn't work :(

Comment: check if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3667412/call-one-stored-procedure-inside-other-stored-procedure-on-different-servers

Comment: I am not sure how to call it from Oracle but in SQL Server not only do you have to setup a Linked Server in SQL Server Management Studio between the source and destination servers but alo as Bumble Bee indicated you have to use things like [SERVER_NAME]. [DB].[OWNER].[OBJECT] as names of what you are trying to call. I have once connected my sql server SP to call a Oracle table to read from by doing the above and also any machine that wants to have connectivity to Oracle will need Oracle Client Tools installed on it AND the file tnsnames.ora file poiting to the right Oracle box, ect.